# Local Kernel for Rate Data

Tags: regression, nonparametric, kernel-smoothing

Perhaps a naive question here. Is there a local kernel-based approach that is appropriate for modeling rate data of the form y/z, in which y can be 0 but z never is? Omitting z and measuring the mean value of y within a certain bandwidth would introduce bias by ignoring the fact that all observations are not of equal size. But scaling y by z initially would also introduce bias due to cases in which y is 0.

More generally, the quantity I am trying to recover can be thought of as: sum(y)/sum(z) within a given bandwidth.